# IE Window not coming to foreground, after it was setParent to windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, foreground, setparent

I have a windows form with Tabs, in each tab i have IE browsers embedded in it using `SetParent()` api.

```
SetParent((IntPtr)explorer.HWND, parent);
```

There is another application say notepad is on top of my form and when I click on embeded IE browser, though IE get activated but it doesn't come on top and notepad remains on top in a deactivated state.

I also tried setting forground using `SetForegroundWindow((IntPtr)explorer.HWND)` in side a timer that keeps track of mouse clicks. The code was executed but with no success.

I also tried.

```
SetWindowPos((IntPtr)explorer.HWND, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SetWindowPosFlags.IgnoreResize | SetWindowPosFlags.IgnoreMove );

SwitchToThisWindow(GetParentHandle(windowClicked), false);

BringWindowToTop(GetParentHandle(windowClicked));
```

but with no success.

Comment: This is something that Windows had to support to provide compatibility with Windows 3.x programs.  IE most certainly is not a 3.x program.  Use the WebBrowser control.

Comment: I can not use WebBrowser, i need an IE object as it runs in different process which is desirable for my application.

Comment: Its not just IE, i also have third party windows application that i need to setParent in my form.